R studio too slow when it starts
The last couple of months Rstudio has become extremely slow when it opens. I may need more than a minute waiting for it to open. I know that there are a couple of posts in the community which deal with the problem. I tried them all but without success.
None of the suggestions shown below (and several others that I could not trace them back) worked in my case. Any help would be very much appreciated.
I tried all I could find in stackoverflow and in posit community; for example, I ...

... uninstalled and reinstalled R and Rstudio, deleting the relevant AppData and Local hidden folders, making sure that the home
ensure that the home directory is in my local machine (and not a subfolder in VPN or proxy folder etc.)
ran the rm(list=ls()) and the ipconfig /flushdns that I found here Rstudio takes long time to start
checked out sys.getenv() and tried the solutions suggested at R / RStudio Painfully Slow
whitelist Rstudio in my firewall (BitDefender) because I found a relevant issue here R Studio Too Slow to Run
disable, enable and redisable Git Version control
ran gctorture(FALSE) that I found here Rstudio is painfully slow

I checked the log files, and the Sys.getenv() commands, but I cannot be sure whether I can spot the problem.
As said, none of the above steps worked for me. Any help would be very much appreciated.
